# How to pass http call into getData function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, offset, ngtable

The records in my activity log page is limited to maximum of 100. 
I’m trying to find a way to have pagination on the page. Setting at 50 records per page. 
Is there a way to pass `$http.get(‘/api/activity’)` calls into getData function and add an offset on the http call so offset number would change every time the page number changes?

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('ActivityLogController', function($scope, $log, $rootScope, $http, $state, $interval, $stateParams, NgTableParams, $filter) {
  return $scope.initActivity = function() {
    return $http.get('/api/activity').then(function(response) {
      $scope.activity = _.map(response.data, function(activity) {
        var ref, ref1;
        if (activity.User) {
          activity.name = ((ref = activity.User) != null ? ref.firstName : void 0) + " " + ((ref1 = activity.User) != null ? ref1.lastName : void 0);
        } else {
          activity.name = "Null User";
        }
        return activity;
      });
      $scope.activity = _.orderBy($scope.activity, ['createdAt'], ['desc']);
      return $scope.activityTable = new NgTableParams({
        sorting: {
          day: 'asc'
        },
        page: 1,
        count: 50
      }, {
        total: $scope.activity.length,
        counts: [],
        getData: function($defer, params) {
          var filteredData, orderedData, slicedData;
          filteredData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.activity, params.filter()) : $scope.activity;
          orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) : filteredData;
          slicedData = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
          return $defer.resolve(slicedData);
        }
      });
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: Not sure about the offset part, but for doing the ajax call inside `getData()`, you just need to return the promise from the `$http` call: `getData: function($defer, params) { return $http.get('/api/activity').then(function(data){ return data.slice(...); }); }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use promises inside the `getData` function and return the array what you want display.

```
var Api = $resource("/data");
this.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
  getData: function(params) {
    // ajax request to api
    return Api.get(params.url()).$promise.then(function(data) {
      params.total(data.inlineCount); // recal. page nav controls
      return data.results;
    });
  }
});
```

you can see this example working on the page of Ng-Table

[Ng-Table with a promise](http://ng-table.com/#/loading/demo-external-array)

Comment: I think he wants to use `$http` and not the `$resource`

Comment: it's the same, he can replace it, the function should work if it returns an array